# How can I write the equivalent of this formula for non integer n and k in terms of gamma functions?

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

I am wondering how can I write the following formula for non integer parameters?

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!n!}{k!(2n-k)!}.\frac{(-1)^{(n-k)}}{(n-k)}}$$

I have searched some pages like [Particular values of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function), especially between those formulas that have $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}$ and also [Gamma function properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gamma_function&action=edit&section=8#Properties). But I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

You can always replace
factorials by the Gamma function
by using
$\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$.

A problem I see is
figuring out
what the summation means
when $n$ is not an integer.

Comment: yeah, my problem is that summation. I thought maybe there is some way to solve this in math. like showing it by an integral, etc. But I couldn't find